# Define custom twig page template for specific pages by page url - page--program.html.twig

Tags: theming

I have multiple pages with different content type. All the pages 1st path component is same. So, I want to define a custom twig page template to these pages by their 1st path component.

Eg. I have pages with the URL like **program/one**, **program/two**, **program/three** and **program/ten** from the different content type and I want to apply **`page--program.html.twig`** template only these specific pages by checking their 1st path component (eg. program/*).

Anyone help me, how to do this?

Comment: See [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.4.x)

Comment: In this case you don't need this, because path components are added to page templates automatically, so `page--program.html.twig` should work out of the box for ' /program/*'

Comment: @4k4 I assumed he had nodes with pathauto configured as `/program/*`. IIRC, aliases are not counted for such template suggestions. He has to either use `page--node--[nid].html.twig` or make the suggestions himself. If that's the case @PunyaRuchal see: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205567/template-suggestions-based-on-path-alias